# CustomValidation using OnServerValidate and ClientValidationFunction

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, customvalidator

I have problems in using CustomValidation control, I want to check if year entered in  date of birth text field is less than graduation year selected from a drop down list by 20 years. I think using ClientValidationFunction is much better when i tried to use it:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="BirthYearCustomValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlGraduationYear" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid graduation year." SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="SaveEducationStep" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="GraduationYearValidation"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GraduationYearValidation(sender, args) {

    var brithYear = parseInt(new Date(document.getElementById('<%=txtBirthDate.ClientID%>').value).getFullYear());

    var gradeYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=ddlGraduationYear.ClientID%>').options[document.getElementById('<%=ddlGraduationYear.ClientID%>').selectedIndex].text);

    if ((brithYear - gradeYear) < 20) {
        return args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else {
        return args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

I get those errors: document.getElementById(...) is null and GraduationYearValidation is not defined.

so, i tried to make it server side by:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="BirthYearCustomValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlGraduationYear" ErrorMessage="enter a valid graduation year." SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="SaveEducationStep" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="BirthYearCustomValidator_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

code behind is :

```
protected void BirthYearCustomValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        int brithYear = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBirthDate.Text).Year;
        int gradeYear = Convert.ToInt32(ddlGraduationYear.SelectedValue);

        if ((gradeYear - brithYear) < 20)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

it doen't work and i searched for the reason i found it may be because i need to write `Page.Validate("SaveEducationStep");` and check if `Page.IsValid` before save, but it still not working with me
any suggestion on both scenarios will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: why dont you use `asp:CompareValidator`

Comment: i tried it but i think it's `ValueToCompare` while setting it through code behind must be string and i need to compare integers ?

Comment: You really need to detail when you say "it doesn't work". Does it reach the server? Does it reach the server validation method?

Comment: It doesn't reach server validation method.

Answer (score 0):

client side validation  is working, check your code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dddate" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="2014" Value="2014"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2013" Value="2013"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2012" Value="2012"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2011" Value="2011"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ValidateEmptyText="true" EnableClientScript="true"             runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ValidationGroup="test" ClientValidationFunction="abc" ControlToValidate="dddate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="test" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function abc(sender, args) {


        var birthYear = parseInt(new Date(document.getElementById('<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').value).getFullYear());

            var gradeYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=dddate.ClientID%>').options[document.getElementById('<%=dddate.ClientID%>').selectedIndex].text);
            if ((gradeYear - birthYear) > 20) {
                return args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else {
                return args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }


</script>
```

Comment: I get `document.getElementById('<%=txtDate.ClientID%>') is null`,
while trying to but `$(document).ready(function GraduationYearValidation(sender, args){...});` i get GraduationYearValidation is not defined.